# Zoom/Pinch the pdf which is loaded in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, resourcebundle, pinchzoom

I have loaded a PDF file in a UIWebView from the resource bundle.

Now, I am not able to zoom/pinch the PDF file.

I found the below 2 relevant links, but none of the answers are marked as correct -

1. [How to zoom webView with pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758544/how-to-zoom-webview-with-pdf-file)
2. [Enable zooming/pinch on UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134576/enable-zooming-pinch-on-uiwebview)

How to make the PDF zoomable/pinchable which has been loaded in a UIWebView from the resource bundle, Will the below solution work ?

1. [Problem with pdf while opening in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676943/problem-with-pdf-while-opening-in-uiwebview)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions found?

Comment: Why not using the Quick Look framework to show pdf files?

Comment: only **yourwebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;** enable zooming in webView nothing-need other extra code simply load PDF in webviwe and scalesPageToFit put yes

Answer (score 8):

In your WebView on **Interface Builder** add check to **Scale Page To Fit** and you enable a Pinch ZoomIn ZoomOut ;)

Or if you want to lad better your PDF try to Look this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:@"http:pdfURL"]];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourPDFFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    //--------------AND HERE USE SCALE PAGE TO FIT------------------//
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

}
```

[image: UIWebView]
Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

//Try like this

```
NSString *urlstr=@"www.example.com/yy.pdf";
web=nil;
web=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 98, 320, 367)];
web.delegate=self;
[self.view addSubview:web];
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr]]];
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pgr = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
 pgr.delegate = self;
 [web addGestureRecognizer:pgr];
```

// Target Action

```
 - (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
 {
  recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
recognizer.scale = 1;
  }
```

Before this add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in .h. Hope it will helps you..

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory]) 
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strFileName];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [webview loadRequest:request];
}
```